# Retrieve User Stories and associated Test Cases with it

Tags: rally, excel-addins

I am using Rally excel add-in and trying to retrieve User Stories and associated Test Cases. I added additional column to the report "User Story" to retrieve TestCase.Name and also tried TestCase.FormattedID. In both cases I receive empty column. What am I doing wrong? 
Also there is a column "Number of Test Cases" that also always returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a custom app that builds a grid of user stories and associated test cases. Looks like this is the data you want to display:

[image]

The code is available in [this git hub repo](https://github.com/nmusaelian-rally/test-cases-of-stories). You may copy/paste the html file into a custom page.

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'iteration',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select an Iteration:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },

   onScopeChange: function() {
        Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'UserStory',
            fetch: ['FormattedID','Name','TestCases'],
            pageSize: 100,
            autoLoad: true,
            filters: [this.getContext().getTimeboxScope().getQueryFilter()],
            listeners: {
                load: this._onDataLoaded,
                scope: this
            }
        }); 
    },

     _onDataLoaded: function(store, data){
                var stories = [];
                var pendingTestCases = data.length;

                Ext.Array.each(data, function(story) {
                            var s  = {
                                FormattedID: story.get('FormattedID'),
                                Name: story.get('Name'),
                                _ref: story.get("_ref"),
                                TestCaseCount: story.get('TestCases').Count,
                                TestCases: []
                            };

                            var testcases = story.getCollection('TestCases');
                            testcases.load({
                                fetch: ['FormattedID'],
                                callback: function(records, operation, success){
                                    Ext.Array.each(records, function(testcase){
                                        s.TestCases.push({_ref: testcase.get('_ref'),
                                                        FormattedID: testcase.get('FormattedID'),
                                                        Name: testcase.get('Name')
                                                    });
                                    }, this);

                                    --pendingTestCases;
                                    if (pendingTestCases === 0) {
                                        this._createGrid(stories);
                                    }
                                },
                                scope: this
                            });
                            stories.push(s);
                }, this);
    } ,            

    _createGrid: function(stories) {
        var myStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.custom.Store', {
                data: stories,
                pageSize: 100,  
            });
        if (!this.grid) {
        this.grid = this.add({
            xtype: 'rallygrid',
            itemId: 'mygrid',
            store: myStore,
            columnCfgs: [
                {
                   text: 'Formatted ID', dataIndex: 'FormattedID', xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Rally.ui.renderer.template.FormattedIDTemplate')
                },
                {
                    text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'Name'
                },
                {
                    text: 'TestCase Count', dataIndex: 'TestCaseCount'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Test Cases', dataIndex: 'TestCases', flex:1,
                    renderer: function(value) {
                        var html = [];
                        Ext.Array.each(value, function(testcase){
                            html.push('<a href="' + Rally.nav.Manager.getDetailUrl(testcase) + '">' + testcase.FormattedID + '</a>' + ' ' + testcase.Name);
                        });
                        return html.join(', ');
                    }
                }
            ]
        });

         }else{
            this.grid.reconfigure(myStore);
         }
    }
});
```

If you prefer to filter by Releases, not Iterations, you may change `scopeType` of `Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp`

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.TimeboxScopedApp',
    componentCls: 'app',
    scopeType: 'release',
    comboboxConfig: {
        fieldLabel: 'Select a Release:',
        labelWidth: 100,
        width: 300
    },
```

As far as Excel addin, I do not see a column available on a User Story query that would display test cases associated with a story. Since TestCases is a collection on HierarchicalRequirement object in [WS API](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) a separate query has to be made to get to individual Test Cases. That's what I did in the code above.

Here is a screenshot from my Excel plugin. There is TestCaseStatus, which is expected, but TestCases collection is not included since the collection will only return a uri. Perhaps you are using a custom tool to export from Rally to Excel.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution. Question: how to get rid of the "iteration" drop down, since we actually operate on "Release" terms.

Comment: Also I found another solution to my question: create report in Rally, then export it as .csv and then write some excel macro to parse it properly. Do you know if it is possible actually to download Rally report as plain raw data, before they apply grouping on it (showing it as Pivot report on UI)?

Comment: You may change scopeType form iteration to release. I updated the post with that info. The way to get a 'raw data' is to query WS API directly, but if you need to get elements of a collection, two separate requests are needed - one on user stories, that includes the test cases collection, and then on the collection itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use TestCases.FormattedID, it will give all linked test cases in single cell separated by comma.