# User stories and associated test cases filtered by Projects (not by Iteration)

Tags: rally

I am trying to extract test cases belonging to a set of user stories, but I need to **filter them by Projects**, and not by Iterations or Release.

Is there a way to filter them this way?

Comment: What toolkit are you using?  Have you written any code yet?  TestCases can be queried by project like any other artifact...

Comment: I used the code from here- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691053/retrieve-user-stories-and-associated-test-cases-with-it
I tried to change the scope in the code to Project, but it is not showing me any output.

Comment: Can you share your code?  I don't think you should need an additional project picker in your app since it's easy to change the global project scoping in the nav...